# Multivariable Normal Distribution: find linear estimation

Tags: normal-distribution

[the MVN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fUcc.png)

$X=
\begin{pmatrix}
X1\\X2\\X3 
\end{pmatrix}
\sim N3
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\2\\3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{align}
11\quad 
-6\quad
2 \\
-6\quad
10\quad
-4 \\
2\quad
-4 \quad
6
\end{align}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}$

Given a three variable MVN, X=(X1, X2, X3) ~N((1,2,3), sigma), mean vector(1,2,3) and a covariance matrix as in the image, find the linear approximation of X3 by a linear function of X1 and X2

I am not sure how to discover the relation between these variables, all I can think of is the mean value have a relationship of X3=X2+X1 and since sigma is a covariance matrix, I can see no obvious quantifiable relation between the variables except whether they have same trends. Pls help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: sry, still new to the forum, I will have a quick look over the MathJax